# Curl get of .cgi file, Always 504 gateway time out

Tags: php, curl, 504

I have a ip cam and I use Get method to switch on the alarm.

When I use browser everything is ok

```
http://da***.com:808/set_alarm.cgi?user=***&pwd=***&motion_armed=1"
```

If a try to use this php file I always obtain  "504 gateway time out"

```
<?php

    function httpGet($url)
      {
        $ch = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

        $output=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
      }

     echo httpGet("http://da***.com:808/set_alarm.cgi?user=***&pwd=***&motion_armed=1");
?>
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you are requesting some script from the same server, and `504`
is likely due to only one PHP backend process, So when you request from browser its only one request and is getting server.

If you are using php-cgi, configuring environment variable before starting php-cgi, hope it helps.

> set PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=0
>
> set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=10000`

Check that your backend can handle multiple requests simultaneously and that your script doesn't somehow create a dead-look (requesting the output of itself).

Check FCGI logs. If that doesn't help, increment the debug levels on nginx.